# Save image in SD card after picasso load image

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am using `picasso` plugin to load image.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(BackendConfig.media_url+folder+holder.media_name).resize(150, 150).into(holder.imageView);
```

It's working fine. But, I want to save that image in SD card by loading just once from `URL`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Picasso using LRU disk cache, no need to worry about loading it from URL once. If you need to load and save actual image as file, load it as bitmap resource instead, and use [Bitmap.compress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) and [FileOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to save into file (PNG/JPEG/WEBP).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this lightweight android library [VINCI](https://github.com/abbashosseini/Vinci) (wrot this for my self) its do every thing you want

- caching - using `LruCache`
- managing `files/bitmaps` (Saving files in *internalStorage*)

read this WIKI [part](https://github.com/abbashosseini/Vinci/wiki/File-Saving) for more visit my github [repo](https://github.com/abbashosseini/Vinci) .

```
Storage store = Vinci.base(context).process().load(uri).file();

Log.e("Created", Boolean.toString(store.isCreated()));
Log.e("FileObject", store.FileObject().toString());
Log.e("FullPath", store.getfullPath().getPath());
Log.e("LocalPath", store.LocalPath());
Log.e("Get Bitmap File", String.valueOf(store.getBitmap()));
```